# warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments

Tags: iphone, objective-c

When i run the below code

```
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Response count is %d",response.products.count]);
```

i get a warning message like below

warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments

what is the problem in my syntax..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to create another autoreleased string, just pass it straight to `NSLog`:

```
NSLog(@"Response count is %d",response.products.count);
```

The reason why this warning is popping up is because you didn't supply a format string as the first argument to `NSLog`.